# Urls behing Geocoding methods of Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps, geocoding, firewall

I have a problem where the GeoCoding methods are not working in a particular network. I believe it is due to the firewall blocking the url behind these methods. So It would help if you could provide me the **Urls used behind the following methods**, so that I can get them whitelisted in the network:
- **GetAddressesForPositionAsync**
- **GetPositionsForAddressAsync**

PS - Xamarin Forms Maps v2.4.0.74863

Comment: Which platforms are you deploying to? Each platform implements the geocoding functionality separately.

Comment: @hankide I am deploying on Android and iOS